# How to instantiate a super class static variable in sub class as final

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, class-variables

I am simulating a parking lot application. And have a class `Vehicle` which is abstract and extended by concrete classes like `Car`, `Truck` etc. I have a variable `parkingFare` which for each sub class of `Vehicle` will be instantiated as class variable and final so that all instances of that particular class can use the same value. e.g If I set `parkingFare` for `Car` as $2 it should be the same for all instances of `Car`. The problem is I am unable to access this variable in my concrete class as class variable.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

 String plateNo;
 LocalTime startTime;
 static int parkingFare;
 public abstract int getFare();
 public abstract String getPlateNo();
 public abstract LocalTime getParkedTime();

}


 public class Car extends Vehicle {

  final parkingFare = 2; // how I want to instantiate it.
   public Car(String plateNo){
    this.plateNo = plateNo;
    this.startTime = LocalTime.now();     
   }

   @Override
   public LocalTime getParkedTime(){
    return startTime;
   }

   @Override
   public String getPlateNo(){
    return plateNo;
   } 

   @Overrid
   public int getFare(){
    return parkingFare;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Looks like you declare an int as a method. `public abstract int getFare();` You can do `public abstract int getFare1 = getFare();`

Comment: @WonderWorld `getFare` method is not my problem as of now. its initializing the static variable in sub class

Comment: I mean you can't write `public abstract int getFare()` afaik. the `()` means its a method. (i know it's not the problem at the moment, just saying.) :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this in Your SubClass

```
static {
 parkingFare=10;
}
```

> Since A static variable is related to a class not in the instance, so
>   all instances of Class will share the static variable.

So after initializing `parkingFare=10` all the instances of `Class Car` will have the same parking fare .

Now Coming to your Comment you need to make them final in child class you can't  ,if you want to make them `final` you need to declare `parkingFare` as final itself in `Vehicle Class`

Comment: If you want them to be final then make them final  in your abstractClass itself .

Answer (score 1):

Use a static-block:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    static {
        parkingFare = 2;
    }

    // ...
}
```

However, this makes parkingFare equal in all Vehicle-classes, regardless of subclass. For example, having another Vehicle subclass Bus setting parkingFare = 10 and running:

```
Car car = new Car("Car");
Bus bus = new Bus("Bus");
System.out.println(car.getFare());
System.out.println(bus.getFare());
```

Results in 10 being printed twice.

Adding parkingFare to each subclass will solve this.

(Double edit: confused with how java stores static variables, but then I tested, and the current description is accurate)

Comment: removing it from `Vehicle` class and adding it to all sub classes as static final should work..?

Comment: @Rolf , regarding to your previous comment : `A static variable is related to a class not in the instance, so all instances of Class will share the static variable. This is how java handles Static variables` , Now coming to your edited part of answer : it's a matter of initialization , if you are in a Bus class and static block  set the fare to 10 it will remain 10 for both the calls since same static variable shared , Now if you are in Car Class then  2 will be printed because of it's initialization as `2`

Comment: Yes, that was how I thought it would work, and I tested and got different results due to errors in my test-code, so I was confused not regarding java but regarding my own coding errors...

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to make *cars* cost 2$, then you should move the static final variable to that class.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

 String plateNo;
 LocalTime startTime;
 public abstract int getFare();
 public abstract String getPlateNo();
 public abstract LocalTime getParkedTime();

}


 public class Car extends Vehicle {

   static final int parkingFare = 2;

   ...
   @Override
   public final int getFare() {
     return parkingFare;
   }   
}
```